# Send cell string value with button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hello I have working json parsing with custom cell and i have some label values and i added buttons for every cell and i want to take ID when clicked button on cell. My codes here

In My Tableview codes

```
  cell.IDLabel.text= ID;
  cell.cellButton1.tag=200+indexPath.row;
```

Button Action

```
- (IBAction)didTapCellButton1:(UIButton *)sender {


    int *myrow = sender.tag-199;  // Now i know which row clicked with this code ,  But i want to know IDLabel value when this button clicked

}
```

i know which row clicked  with didTapCellButton1 action code ,  But i want to send IDLabel value when this button clicked

Thank you !

Comment: I hope you plan to change `row` from `int *` to `int`.

Comment: Once you know the row, get the data from your data source.

Comment: @maddy hi maddy yes i know data source IDLabel value looking good but i need only send it when Button1 clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally . I found easy way :)

My working codes here;

```
 cell.IDLabel.text= ID;

 int valueid = [cell.IDLabel.text intValue];

  cell.cellButton1.tag=valueid;
```

And when button clicked

```
 int myvalue = sender.tag;
```

I think will be help too many people

thanks !

Comment: Again, I hope you plan to change `myvalue` from `int *` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create `@protocol` for your custom cell, something like `- (void)myCustomCellDidSelectButton:(MyCustomCell *)cell`, than implement delegate in your ViewController and set `cell.delegate = self` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Now when your button's action fires inside cell call delegate method. When you have cell you can check your ID even without your DataSource.

Comment: great idea but I'm new in obj c i don't know how can i do this :( Im still working about 9-10 hours i didn't resolve it dude.